# Mimic anchor behavior (new window when pressting 'ctl') when submitting a form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

This may be a retarded question, but is there an elegant way to mimic the behavior of an anchor tag when submitting a form? I'd like my users to be able to hold down the control key while submitting a form and have the result open in a new window. Right now I'm using a funky, unreliable javascript workaround that I'm embarrassed to post here. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use jQuery, then you can do it like this. Let's say that you have form

```
<form id="test">
    (...)
    <input type="submit" id="test_submit" />
</form>
```

Bind a `keydown` and `keyup` events to it like this

```
$('#test').keydown(function(e) {
   if (e.keyCode == /* here put the key code of CTRL which I don't remember */ )
       $(this).data('ctrl', true);
});
$('#test').keyup(function(e) {
    $(this).data('ctrl', false);
});
```

and then handle the click event on submit button

```
$('#test_submit').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // do the serialization and post via AJAX
    if ($('#test').data('ctrl'))
    {
        // do the new window creation
    }
    else
    {
        // update this window url
    }
});
```

I hope that this works, cause I didn't test it. :)

Comment: Didn't quite work out of the box, but it did the trick with a few minor tweaks. As usual, jQuery provides a much more elegant way to do the same job. Thank you for putting me on the right path!